# How to prove trig partial sum to -1

Tags: summation

I was struggling with finding a proof to prove:
$$
\sum_{0\leq n \leq \alpha -1} \cos{\frac{2n\pi}{\alpha}} = -1
$$

I know it's true but I cannot figure out how to prove it,

Sorry to ask such a simple question,

And many thanks to whoever can help.

Comment: First notice that $1=\cos 2\alpha\pi/\alpha$  so you can move the $-1$ to the other side and make the sum run to $\alpha.$  Second, half of your angles are in the 2nd and 3rd quadrants, so their cosines are negatives of those in the 1st and 4th quadrants.

Comment: Presumably $\alpha$ is an integer greater than 1. One way would be to use the complex number definition of $\cos$. Another would be to pair up terms as per @Goddard.

Comment: Actually - it's not true for $\alpha=2$ either!

Comment: Maybe double check the question. Should the saum start at n=1?